# PCA of date and Country

Tags: r, pca

I am working on data set and want to analyze data set.I want to do PCA of DATE, Country and Number of people. How can i generate PCA plot of this data set in R ? From where i should start?I tried with normal method but didn't worked. data set

```
03/17/2020  US  5
03/17/2020  Philippines 1
03/17/2020  Canada  14
03/17/2020  Romania 6
03/17/2020  Thailand    1
03/17/2020  Mainland China  0
03/17/2020  Indonesia   26
03/17/2020  Saudi Arabia    2
03/17/2020  Mainland China  1
03/17/2020  Hong Kong   4
03/17/2020  US  1
03/17/2020  US  0
03/17/2020  Iraq    5
03/17/2020  Mainland China  0
03/17/2020  US  444
03/17/2020  India   4
03/17/2020  Luxembourg  0
03/17/2020  Mainland China  1
03/17/2020  Mainland China  2
03/17/2020  Mainland China  0
03/17/2020  Kuwait  2
03/17/2020  Mainland China  1
03/17/2020  Lebanon 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the normal method"? Do you mean the ```prcomp``` function?

Comment: i converted data set into factor and then used MCA() functions.is it good practice ?

Comment: errr... you cannot do pca? Two columns are categorical and the last column is continuous?

Comment: is there any other way i can do PCA?

Comment: There is no ```MCA()``` function in base r. What package(s) are you using? And I think @StupidWolf is right, if that's your whole dataset I don't think a PCA would work, or if it does then how helpful it would be